# Custom basemap not showing surroundings in CartoDB

Tags: carto, basemap

I have entered the following png into the XYZ URL for the Carto custom map but it is not working (for either my link below or their example link). I keep getting my custom map, which I rectified on Map Warper, just floating in blank space:

My rectified map:
[image: myrectified]

The image I see on Carto: 
[image: carto image]

[The Carto blog on the topic.](https://carto.com/blog/cartodb-x-mapwarper/)

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Can you share the xyz basemap url?

Answer (score 2):

Adding a custom XYZ means you remove any other basemap so if your image does not cover the world, well then you get an image in the middle of a blank space. BUILDER only allows one basemap layer below your CARTO data.

If you want to combine basemaps and your image you need to create a custom [CARTO.js](https://carto.com/documentation/cartojs/) application where you add as many Leaflet/Google Maps layers you want below your CARTO data.